# Twain Module Raise an Exception : twain.excTWCC_SEQERROR

Tags: python, twain

I have developing a  software using [twain module](http://twainmodule.sourceforge.net/) in `python` . This software based on `PyQt4` . I have connecting to scanner and scanning lots of file with these code:

```
import twain

sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
ss = sm.OpenSource()
ss.RequestAcquire(0,0)

while True:
    rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
    if rv is None:
        break
    else:
        (handle, count) = rv
        twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, '{}.bmp'.format(uuid.uuid4()))
```

when the scanning operations has finished, the images saved like .bmp file . Everthing is OK but throws an exception and programs can't execute the other line of codes . The exception message is :

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/34Deneme/dene.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/34Deneme/dene.py", line 13, in <module>
    rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 1841, in XferImageNatively
    rv, handle = self._get_native_image()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 1787, in _get_native_image
    (TWRC_XFERDONE, TWRC_CANCEL))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 1453, in _call
    return self._sm._call(self._id, dg, dat, msg, buf, expected_returns)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 2094, in _call
    raise exc
twain.excTWCC_SEQERROR
Exception ignored in: <bound method SourceManager.__del__ of <twain.SourceManager object at 0x004EEA10>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 2059, in __del__
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twain.py", line 2066, in close
  File "C:\Python34\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 101, in pop
KeyError: 'pop from empty WeakSet'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So what is the problem ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import twain

sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
ss = sm.OpenSource()
ss.RequestAcquire(0,0)
try:
  while True:
    rv = ss.XferImageNatively()
    if rv is None:
        break
    else:
        (handle, count) = rv
        twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, '{}.bmp'.format(uuid.uuid4()))  
except:
  print "Error!"
```

Comment: I suggest you explain what you're doing here. This would help create searchable content for everybody.